# Running Android apps in Linux

Tags: android

I have a Red Hat Linux (RHL) system on which I'd like to run Android apps. How would I do this? Is there an open-source port of the Android Runtime for linux? Kind of like a VM?
If not, what steps will I need to follow to port the runtime to RHL (with the Dalvik VM etc) so that I can run the android apps built by all android developers?
I am new to android so I am trying to understand if there is an application virtualization support for it from anyone. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will be able to run them, it's working in progress. And this feature will bring Linux to desktops. Stay tuned!

Comment: @lzap That's exciting!! Could you give us a little more detail? For example what is the name of the project, and who are behind it? Thanks!

Comment: Well it's all bellow, read it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know there is a project for porting Android on x86 platform. You can find iso to download and you can install on LiveCD : http://code.google.com/p/live-android/. You can find more information here

Comment: I think It's not what people want. Adnroid is a good OS for smartphone but not for computer. What user716222 and what I'm lookinf for is a Android VM for Linux (or Windows) to be able to run Android Apps.

Comment: Could be wrong but this project looks dead.  I don't see any versions released after 2009.

Answer (score 16):

You need to use [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) to convert an APK file to a JAR and then you need [IcedRobot](https://github.com/icedrobot/) to run the Android stack above OpenJDK. Maybe I will try to emulate AndroidGL with [JOGL 2.0](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) (it supports both OpenGL and OpenGL-ES). Keep in mind that it is not trivial.

The emulator of [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) is quite slow but you just have to enter adb install my_file.apk to install your application.

You can run [android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org) in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) or [Live Android](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/) from a Live CD as [Dimitri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314862/dimitri) suggested but I'm not sure it is what you want.

P.S: The most promising solution seemed to be [AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/).

P.S 2: ARChon Runtime works very well on 64-bits systems. [This tutorial](http://digiwonk.wonderhowto.com/how-to/run-android-apps-chrome-for-windows-mac-linux-0157523/) is very helpful to make it work.

P.S 3: [App Runtime for Chrome Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) is even more promising, it's currently in beta. The final version will support all Android APIs in Google Chrome under GNU Linux (including Chrome OS), Mac OS X and Windows.

Comment: Hi @gouessej . I have a project about running  Android's OpenGL API on platforms supporting  awt Canvas. [GitHub](https://github.com/AlessandroBorges/madri-gles). Still under development due other project to bind Vulkan on Java...

Comment: Why not using JOGL to access OpenGL-ES instead of LibGDX + your own JNI code?

Comment: I'm not using LibGDX. At the time I start it, I needed a very thin layer for GLES,  in order to make portable applications for Android and desktop platforms. So I choose to implement **android.opengl** API in desktop environment.  It also easy prototyping Android GLES applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just run Android apps - you will need the entire underlying Android operating system. That goes beyond a simple JVM. EDIT: There is actually a project in the works that aims to do that, see Dimitri's link.

But you're in luck - the Android SDK comes with an emulator that should fulfill your needs (although it's a bit on the slow side - if you're developing Android apps, you definitely want to use a physical device instead). The SDK is available [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: "You can't just run Windows apps - you will need the entire underlying Windows operating system" — the truth is in wine. Do I miss something in case with android? Please, elaborate then.

Answer (score 0):

Run Bluestacks on Windows on VMWare on Linux. Easy.